# Google Drive listChildren Stopped working

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have a little php script that's supposed to get files from google drive.  It's been working for months, and suddenly stopped. The listChildren() method returns an object with an empty items array:

```
object(Google_ChildList)#2 (8) {
  ["etag"]=>
  string(57) ""ft0vWwGLra-c-cl2j_y_UrVn1UQ/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8""
  ["__itemsType":protected]=>
  string(21) "Google_ChildReference"
  ["__itemsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["items"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["kind"]=>
  string(15) "drive#childList"
  ["nextLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["nextPageToken"]=>
  NULL
  ["selfLink"]=>
  string(79) "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0BwwPoJj-4FnGTjBScFJ1XzRycE0/children"
}
```

When I enter the id of the folder in the APIs Explorer: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list I get the list correctly.

What happened?  I don't think I changed anything.

Comment: can you post some of the code that do the listing?

Comment: So I found somebody who had a similar problem, and his problem was that he hadn't shared the folder with his service account.  My folder is a public folder, so I didn't think I needed to do that, but in desperation, I tried that.  It worked!  Then, just to test, I un-shared the service account, and the code still worked.  

So, unlikely as it seems, I can only conclude that there was some sort of hiccup with the Google Drive API, that was fixed by re-saving the folder permissions.

Just maybe it wasn't my fault: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$service->files->listFiles(array('q' => "'<FOLDER_ID>' in parents"));
```

[Error on list files using folderId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786381/error-on-list-files-using-folderid/47815626#47815626)