# Error on list files using folderId

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I need to list files by folderId

Using the reference code.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list

```
ERROR : Call to a member function listChildren() on null
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: use This code
`$service->files->listFiles(array('q' => "'<FOLDER_ID>' in parents"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use This code `$service->files->listFiles(array('q' => "'<FOLDER_ID>' in parents"));`